# List validation in drools

Tags: java, drools

A drools newbie here,
Following is the java class structure.

```
public class Person {
 List<PersonAddress> personAddress;
}

public enum AddressType {
 CURRENT, PREVIOUS;
}
public class PersonAddress{    
  Address address;
  AddressType type
  Integer timeAtAddress;        
}

public class Address {
String city;
String country;
String street;
}
```

I have to write some code to validate PersonAddress in drools.
Rule 1. if person has list of PersonAddress instances, if one of them being AddressType == CURRENT and timeAtAddress < 3, then i want to find whether that list contains a address where AddressType == PREVIOUS.

Rule 2. If above condition is true, then i want to get the PersonAddress instance where AddressType == PREVIOUS,

Drools version 5.5.0.Final,

Java 1.7

Functions can be used

This is something i tried, but it doesnt work

```
  function boolean isPreviousAddressExist(java.util.List list) {
        if(list.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean validRecordFound = false;
        for(int addressIndex = 0; addressIndex < list.size(); addressIndex++) {
            PersonAddress pa = (PersonAddress)list.get(addressIndex);
            if(AddressType.CURRENT.equals(pa.getAddressType()) && pa.getTimeAtAddress() != null && pa.getTimeAtAddress() < 3) {
                validRecordFound =  true;
                break;     
            }
        }
        boolean previousRecordFound = false;
        if(validRecordFound) {
           for(int addressIndex = 0; addressIndex < list.size(); addressIndex++) {
                PersonAddress pa = (PersonAddress)list.get(addressIndex);
                if(AddressType.PREVIOUS.equals(pa.getAddressType())) {
                    previousRecordFound =  true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            previousRecordFound = true;
        }
        return previousRecordFound;
    }

rule "Previous-Physical-Home Address is required for Time at Current-Physical-Home"
when

    $quotation:Quotation()        
    eval(!isPreviousAddressExist($quotation.getApplicantList()))   
then   
    runningResults.addRunningResult(new BusinessRuleRunningResult(null,  " A Previous physical Home Address is required.", false));
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are both rules, using `extends` to avoid the repetirion:

```
rule "brief CURRENT"
when
  Person( $name: name, $pa: personAddress )
  PersonAddress( type == AddressType.CURRENT, timeAtAddress < 3 ) from $pa
then
end
rule "no PREVIOUS"
extends "brief CURRENT"
when
  not PersonAddress( type == AddressType.PREVIOUS ) from $pa
then
  System.out.println( "invalid. " + $name );
end
rule "has PREVIOUS"
extends "brief CURRENT"
when
  $ppa: PersonAddress( type == AddressType.PREVIOUS ) from $pa
then
  System.out.println( "valid. " + $name +
                      " at " + $ppa.getAddress().getCity() );
end
```

This assumes that there is only one CURRENT per Person; if not, the rules might fire more than once. Use `exist` to avoid.

I didn't try to find a bug in your code as "doesn't work" is too vague. Anyway, if you are using rules, what's the point in writing procedural code doing the checks?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what i exactly wanted. As i said, iam a newbie to drools, Our application is full j2ee application, One of our client requested us to do some validation using drools

Comment: Dear @laune, i have another question related to drools, it has been asked [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735964/validation-in-drools), Appreciate, if you could help me on that too

Comment: @laune , Please see this question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201760/arraylist-size-not-working-properly-in-drools-6-2