# Validation in drools

Tags: java, drools

This is the second part of my drools validation question. First part has been already answered and proposed solutions has been implemented in my code.
[First Part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717009/list-validation-in-drools/25718143#25718143)

This is my java class structure

```
public class Person {
 List<PersonAddress> personAddress;
 List<FinanceDetails> financeDetails;
}
public enum AddressStatus {
 CURRENT, PREVIOUS;
}
public enum AddressType {
 PHYSICAL, POSTAL;
}
public enum AddressUseType {
 HOME, OFFICE;
}
public class PersonAddress{    
  Address address;
  AddressType type
  AddressStatus status
  AddressUseType useType
  String ownerShipType
  Integer timeAtAddress;        
}
public class Address {
  String city;
  String country;
  String street;
}
public class FinanceDetails {
  String financeItemName;
  BigDecimal itemValue;
}
```

Ok my problem is, i need to validate itemValue of the FinanceDetails instance if financeItemName is "Land or Building", and if this user has an address which matches following criteria,

AddressStatus == CURRENT

AddressType == PHYSICAL

AddressUseType == HOME

ownerShipType == "Own"

Drools version 5.5.0.Final

Java 1.7

functions can be used

A sample drool rule syntax is needed. Thank you

Comment: The "vote to close" is not to be supported, as this most certainly isn'T "too broad". Perhaps the question ("drools"!) hasn't been understood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Added itemValue tests as seen in some comment**

```
rule "land-orbuilding..."
when
  Peson( $financeDetails: financeDetails, $personAddress: personAddress )
  FinanceDetails( financeItemName == "Land or Building", itemValue == null || itemValue == 0 ) from $financeDetails
  PersonAddress( status == AddressStatus.CURRENT,
                 type == AddressType.PHYSICAL,
                 useType == AddressUseType.HOME,
                 ownerShipType == "Own" ) from $personAddress
then
  //...
end
```

How about reading some of that documentation? This is very much like the "first part", and only a minor variation.

Comment: thanks again for the answer, You are right, this is all bcos i dont understand how drools works. anyway according to given answer, how the rule engine know there is a PersonAddress instance exists for matching criteria hence itemValue of the FinanceDetails should be validated? anyhow this is not getting executed as i wanted. In previous example you have extended another rule, but here it is different.

Comment: Your question says nothing about `itemValue` except "validate". If this doesn't produce the expected result, you may not have asked for what you really want.

Comment: Found the requirement for itemValue in a comment. Next time, put it into the question. And do read some documentation. You can't solve your problems all via stackoverflow!

Comment: i think it is mentioned in the question "i need to validate **itemValue** of the FinanceDetails instance if financeItemName is "Land or Building", and if this user has an address which matches following criteria,"

Comment: "validate" is vague. You may have to check that it is null or not null, greater than (say) 1000 or not less than 0, or zero, or equal to zero. Specs are meant to be **exact**, not assuming that everybody knows what **you** know.

Comment: you helped me a lot, and as before your solution works as expected. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
rule "Check Details"
when
  details:FinanceDetails  (itemValue == 'LAND' || == 'Building')
  address:PersonAddress(status == AddressStatus.CURRENT,
                 type == AddressType.PHYSICAL,
                 useType == AddressUseType.HOME,
                 ownerShipType == "Own" )
then
  modify(details){itemValue=//set your value};
end
```

Comment: thanks, but i cant modify any value in my objects, i just want to validate, validation should be, if there is a matching PersonAddress exists for given criteria, itemValue should not be null or ZERO if the financeItemName is "Land or Building"

Comment: This answer isn't answering the question. It disregards the fields of Person, abd does not show how to extract FinanceDetails and PersonAddress list elements.

Comment: @laune: You are right, I have just given an drools sample example to put the condition of single object of FinanceDetails and PersonAddress.