# How to create dynamic rule engine in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to have dynamic rule engine. As day by day we need to add new constraint for data validation in our project which leads in time waste. We want to have certain mechanism in java or spring boot so that we can dumps rules(constraint) into our database and the rule is executed. Please let us know if any one of you is aware of such mechanism.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735964/validation-in-drools